# How to do virtualhost redirection with appended querystring the right way

Tags: apache2, query-string, virtualhost, redirect

i am confused about some `redirect` rules that i needed to do in `production`. I've seen `a lot of examples in stackoverflow` already and they have build a little bit my `knowledge` about redirection. However i do not have any particular condition aside redirection to a new url with the `exact query string` not matter how it's formed `appended` to it.

Since it's on production, i do have the leisure of try and catch, so i would like to avoid mistakes as much as possible. here is what i think i should do:

```
<VirtualHost X.X.X.X:80>
  ServerName mypoductionserver.com
  ServerAlias cs.myproductionserver.com
  LogLevel warn
  ErrorLog  /var/log/apache2/productionerror.log

  CustomLog /var/log/apache2/productionaccess.log combined

  RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .
  RewriteRule (.*) http://www.newproductionserver.com/? [R=301,L] 
</VirtualHost>
```

THanks for helping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, your RewriteCond says that your query string should consist of one or more characters. If you want the redirect to work even if there's no query string, just remove the condition. Otherwise, you may want to just make it '.+' to clarify that it should be at least one character.

Second, there are two errors in the `RewriteRule`.

First, with your `(.*)` you're capturing the path - but you're never adding it to the new string.

Second, by ending your rule with a `?`, you're erasing the original query string.

The rule should look like:

```
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.newproductionserver.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The `$1` means "use the stuff you captured in the first parenthesis", and removing the `?` means "and don't replace the query string".

Also, in order for any rewrite to work at all, you need to first activate mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On
```